# Restoring the purchases made with codenameone

Tags: in-app-purchase, codenameone, restore

How can I find which IAP-items the user has bought previously with Codename One?
I use the **Purchase** class implementation but the method *getProducts(skus)* returns null and the method *wasPurchased(sku)* throws an exception. 
The more tricky part of the question is: whatif the user has changed his/hers device (same vendor/another device), how can I evaluate what the user has bought/subscribed previously?

best
babür

Answer (score 1):

This is an iOS feature/requirement but it's relatively simple to implement. You can use the `isRestoreSupported` method which will work on iOS.

Then invoke `restore()` which should cause the `paymentSucceeded` callback to be invoked repeatedly with previous purchases from the user.

Comment: Where do you put the callback ? The restore() method does not take a callback as parameter. Would you mind adding details ;-) ?

Comment: The main class needs to implement that interface, notice that the main class is not the state machine but the actual "main" class with the start(), init(Object) methods in it (asking once is sufficient)